# "The list of sources could not be read" error running apt-get update

Tags: apt, upgrade

i get this error when I try to update ubutu

```
root@kuki-HP-Compaq-8200-Elite-SFF-PC:/home/kuki# sudo apt-get update && upgrade
N: Ignoring file 'home:llamaret.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'home:llamaret.list.save.3' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'home:llamaret.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Type 'Reading' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:llamaret.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: There are so many problems in that output, it's hard to pick a place to begin. I'm hung up on the first line: Use of sudo at a root prompt and invalid command `upgrade`. Advice: Slow down. Try to do fewer things, but try to understand each one and do each one correctly. It will save you a lot of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have multiple copies of the file `llamaret.list` in your sources.list.d directory.  You should delete all but the one ending in .list, and the format of that file might not be right either.

If you don't want this software, you can delete all of them.  If you do want it, you should check the installation directions and correct the problems with the one remaining file, possibly by deleting it and re-downloading it.